# HTML 5 and HTTPS

Tags: html, https

Is it possible to use the [offline features of HTML 5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/offline.html#offline) to securely cache and access resources served over HTTPS when offline? Is the local cache encrypted/secure? Are there any gotchas that I should be aware of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the local cache is encrypted. It's the browser's responsibility to protect your data from other websites (like cross-origin), but it doesn't protect your data from whoever has the privilege to access your file system or memory.

Comment: Do you have any information about how different browsers cache encrypted pages?

Comment: I don't think browsers have done anything to protect any local data. It's not their responsibility. IE stores cookie or a like in plain text format. I don't think it would encrypt offline cache. Webkit doesn't encrypt offline data either: http://www.mail-archive.com/webkit-dev@lists.webkit.org/msg05541.html